# Django Model related_name through Multiple Models

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

Hi, I am using the built-in User model object which is referenced in anohter model:

```
 class UserFriend(models.Model):
         user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friends' )
         friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_friends')
         created ...
         hide ...
```

Now, I want to get the user model as related to the friend, I'm trying:

```
 user.user_friends.friend.order('first_name')
```

but I keep getting:
     Cannot resolve keyword 'first_name' into field. Choices are: created, friend, hide, id, modified, user

How can I get this list and loop over them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:

```
 user.friend_user.order_by('friend__first_name')
```

Thanks though for everyone who looked and wanted to help